# Fill matrix with two numbers in a spiral

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, spiral

In the middle of matrix is number x. Matrix is filled with x in a spiral, while the rest is filled with y.

Example:

```
int x=4, y=6, v=7, s=9;
```

OUTPUT:

```
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 4
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 6 4
4 6 6 6 6 6 4 6 4
4 6 4 4 x 6 4 6 4
4 6 4 6 6 6 4 6 4
4 6 4 4 4 4 4 6 4
4 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 4
```

- Note: In the output instead of the letter **x** program should print **4**, but I wrote x to make it easier for understanding task.

Spiral filling looks like --> [this](https://ibb.co/d4jnPCD)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int v = 7, s = 9, x = 4, y = 6, mat[7][9], i, j, l, k;
  for (i = 0; i < v; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < s; j++)
      mat[i][j] = y;
  for (i = 0; i < v; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < s; j++) {
      // spiral goes here
      // mat[i][j] = x;
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < v; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < s; j++) 
      printf("%4d", mat[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: After applying suggestions, now the whole matrix is filled with y. How to make it fill spiral with x?

Comment: You know the exact dimensions of the matrix (`7` by `9`), so why do you create a `100` by `100` matrix? You can use `v` and `s` when creating the matrix, as C allows variable-length arrays.

Comment: Actually I don't know, user should input it. It's easy to write user input so I skipped that part.

Comment: Use even smaller sizes, and use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables or their values. What is the program really doing?

Comment: Changing the values of the loop iterators from inside the loop body is very bad practice, you should refrain from doing so.

Comment: You get no output whatsoever? I find that hard to believe. I think it means that you have problems with executing the program. Can you build and run a HelloWorld successfully? Did you try to remove the quadruple-nested loops and only use the double nested loops for output?

Comment: I needed some time to find what Lundin is referring to. I retract my "hard to believe". Still, what happens if you remove that quad-loop?

Comment: I could write it with double loop, if it's middle print x, else print 0 and that's the best I could write with double loop

Comment: How does the column with all `4` fit the pattern?

Comment: https://ibb.co/0mR6nL0

Comment: I don't get your algorithm.  Are you supposed to start with an array of 6's and then start at 0,0 heading toward the right, and then and fill an inward growing clockwise turning spiral leaving a gap/margin of cell?  I don't get why the right-most column has 4's in it. but the bottom-most row does not.

Comment: This should not require a four-loop nest.  Either (i) fill the whole array with `y` and then trace the path of `x`s until no more `x`s can be within the array bounds, or (ii) find a closed-form way to determine which symbol should appear at each set of coordinates, and loop over the array coordinates (two-loop nest) to apply that to each element.

Comment: @JohnBollinger could you briefly explain this: "fill the whole array with y and then trace the path of xs until no more xs can be within the array bound" how to accomplish that?

Comment: @devec, I assume you understand "fill the whole array with y".  By "trace the path", I mean to simulate walking the required spiral path, setting each matrix element visited to `x` as you go.

Comment: I don't know how to walk the required path, could you give me any idea?

Comment: could anyone post an answer?

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you can get at least 4 different answers depending on which direction you first move from the start point?  Your diagram shows two steps left to start — why 2 steps and not 1 or 3?  Does the number of steps in the initial direction also increase the number of possible answers?  And presumably, at the first turn, the move could be clockwise or anticlockwise?

Comment: I edited diagram --> https://ibb.co/d4jnPCD

Comment: Could you provide answer? This task was given to us by the professor at both the partial and the final exam. I put so much time, but I cannot figure out any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a program for constructing a spiral from the center in an s by v matrix.

Here's the algorithm:

1. The matrix is ​​filled with y values
2. Calculating the center, the cursor cx, cy is set there, 0 is written
3. The spiral drawing direction is set, dir, 1 - left, 2 - down, 3 - right, 4 - up, first 1
4. Draw 1 step by setting x value to matrix
5. If the value in the matrix for dir+1 (if dir+1=5 then dir=1) = y (empty) then dir is incremented by +1. If not (center (0) or already drawn (x)) then dir remains the same.
   If beyond the edge of the matrix, then dir is incremented +1 as if empty, but nothing is drawn.
6. Step 4 is repeated s*v/2 times

The program is compiled with the gcc compiler.

Output:

cx -    4, xy -    3
6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   4
4   4   4   4   4   4   4   6   4
4   6   6   6   6   6   4   6   4
4   6   4   4   0   6   4   6   4
4   6   4   6   6   6   4   6   4
4   6   4   4   4   4   4   6   4
4   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   4

Required:

6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 4
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 6 4
4 6 6 6 6 6 4 6 4
4 6 4 4 x 6 4 6 4
4 6 4 6 6 6 4 6 4
4 6 4 4 4 4 4 6 4
4 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 4

```
#include <stdio.h>


/*
 Increase dir
*/
int incdir (int dir) {

    // direction, 1 - left, 2 - down, 3 - right, 4 - up
    dir++;
    if (dir==5) dir=1;
    return dir;
    
}


/*
 Is coord in matrix
*/
int inmat (int y, int x, int v, int s) {

    // direction, 1 - left, 2 - down, 3 - right, 4 - up
    if (x<0 || x>=s) return 0;
    if (y<0 || y>=v) return 0;
    return 1;

}


/*
 Value in some direction
*/
int dirval(int cx, int cy, int v, int s, int dir, int mat[v][s]) {

    // direction, 1 - left, 2 - down, 3 - right, 4 - up
    
    if (dir==1) {
        if (!inmat(cy, cx-2, v, s)) return -1;
        return mat[cy][cx-2];
        
    }
    if (dir==2) {
        if (!inmat(cy+2, cx, v, s)) return -1;
        return mat[cy+2][cx];
    }
    if (dir==3) {
        if (!inmat(cy, cx+2, v, s)) return -1;
        return mat[cy][cx+2];
    }
    if (dir==4) {
        if (!inmat(cy-2, cx, v, s)) return -1;
        return mat[cy-2][cx];
    }

}


int main() {
  int v = 7, s = 9, x = 4, y = 6, mat[7][9], i, j, l, k;
  
  // cursor
  int cx, cy;
  cx=((int)s/2);
  cy=((int)v/2);
  printf("cx - %4d, xy - %4d\n", cx, cy);
  
  
  
  int dir=1; // direction, 1 - left, 2 - down, 3 - right, 4 - up
  
  int dv;
  
  for (i = 0; i < v; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < s; j++)
      mat[i][j] = y;
  
  mat[cy][cx]=0; // start
  // spiral goes here
  for (i = 0; i < s*v/2; i++) {


    if (dir==1) {
        if (inmat(cy, cx-1, v, s)) mat[cy][cx-1]=x;
        if (inmat(cy, cx-2, v, s)) mat[cy][cx-2]=x;
        cx=cx-2;
    }
    if (dir==2) {
        if (inmat(cy+1, cx, v, s)) mat[cy+1][cx]=x;
        if (inmat(cy+2, cx, v, s)) mat[cy+2][cx]=x;
        cy=cy+2;
    }
    if (dir==3) {
        if (inmat(cy, cx+1, v, s)) mat[cy][cx+1]=x;
        if (inmat(cy, cx+2, v, s)) mat[cy][cx+2]=x;
        cx=cx+2;
    }
    if (dir==4) {
        if (inmat(cy-1, cx, v, s)) mat[cy-1][cx]=x;
        if (inmat(cy-2, cx, v, s)) mat[cy-2][cx]=x;
        cy=cy-2;
    }

    dv=dirval(cx, cy, v, s, incdir(dir), mat);
    if (dv==y || dv==-1) dir=incdir(dir);

  }

  for (i = 0; i < v; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < s; j++) 
      printf("%4d", mat[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Its not difference, this can be any integer except `y` (=6). 0 is used because the matrix is `int` type and "x" can't be set into matrix. But program will work if to set `mat[cy][cx]=4; // start`. And center of the spiral can be set to any place in matrix, not only `cx=(int)s/2;
  cy=(int)v/2;`, with `mat[cy][cx]=4; // start` value set into new center too. And in matrix declaration better to use variables for matrix size not numbers `mat[7][9] -> mat[v][s]`. Thank you.

Comment: And initial direction can be any from 1 - left, 2 - down, 3 - right, 4 - up, this will make spiral go up from center, or right or down, not left only. Program is simple and will work as you want. Good luck with your studies/exams. :)

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration of the inner loop `if (i == v / 2 && j == s / 2)` is always false so you keep doing:

```
        mat[l][k--] = x;  // Decrement k
        mat[l++][j] = y;  // Increment l
```

Now add the inner-loop:

```
                        ------ Increment k
                        |

    for (k = j; k < s; k++) {
      //if (i == v / 2 && j == s / 2)  // Always false when i is zero
      //  mat[i][j] = x;
      //else 
      {
        mat[l][k--] = x;  // Decrement k
        mat[l++][j] = y;  // Increment l
      }
    }
```

So you decrement `k` and the increment `k` in the `for` loop. In other words - `k` doesn't change and you have an endless loop. In that endless loop you keep incrementing `l` and use it as array index. That will access the array out of bounds and crash your program.

Comment: do you have idea how to make this loops do the right thing?

Comment: Well, not your loops. I would use a much simpler approach. I would start by filling the whole matrix with "neutral" value (6) and then draw the spiral afterwards. Much simpler.

Comment: I know to fill all with 6, how to draw spiral afterwards? Could you post your solution for that?